# What versions of pip and python are appropriate for nsdpy?

Tags: python, software-installation

I am currently trying to download all the requirements to make a COInr database, following this workflow; https://mkcoinr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/overview.html.
It requires a couple different third party programs to be able to run, one of them being nsdpy, which it says all it requires is cloning the repo from Github and then you're supposed to simply be able to use 'pip' to install nsdpy.

However I continued to receive this error;
""DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nsdpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nsdpy""

Which makes it seem that my issue is with the version of our Python (I am using a linux system on a Mac). The version of Python that is says we should be using is 2.7, the current version I have downloaded is 3.7.7. But then I was reading through the nsdpy docs (https://nsdpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html#overview) which says that it requires a Python version of 3.8+. So I am a little confused, which version of Python to I truly need to be able to install nsdpy?
Is there a more up to date version of nsdpy?

If anybody else has had this problem and/or has a solution, please let me know!

Comment: To add comment that was lost in migration: I strongly suspect that the version of pip is at fault, as it seems like the issue is that python2.7 is being run, not that it is required.